# Deployment of Mac OS X to iMacs (Dual Booting to windows 7!)

Tags: windows-7, macos, deployment

What is the best solution for DEPLOYMENT of  a dual boot OS (Windows 7 and Mac OS 10.6) to group of 30 iMacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Deploy Studio](http://www.deploystudio.com/Home.html)

Comment: Still looking for a walkthrough on Win7/OSX10.6 deploy- we've tried everything we can think of.

Comment: @Dan - Did you look in the Deploy Studio documentation section of their page? The first link is step by step for this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Boot Camp. It is Mac supported so that takes care of warranty issues, and it also has official Mac support. Also of the two universities I have attended both of them used Boot Camp as their solution. Check out the Boot Camp/Windows 7 [FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986).

Comment: He's not asking how to dual boot, he's asking how to deploy a dual boot. Big difference.

Comment: Sorry, my misread. +1 for MarkM's Deploy Studio.

Comment: Thanks for try guys.  Your right MarkM, we're trying to Deploy with no luck yet.